# Proper use of "Calculation = xlCalculationManual" and similar

Tags: excel, vba

What is the proper use of:

```
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
```

I am using it in this way

```
Sub AAA()
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Call This
Call That
Call Other

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

is this the best way to apply these? or is it better to apply them per `macro?

Thanks

Comment: I put them in a separate sub `Sub GoFast(Optional Reset As Boolean=False)` and just call `GoFast` or `GoFast True`. You can use a Static variable for `CalcMode`. That can get tricky if you're expecting to call that from multiple locations in your code which may overlap though (but then again, so can the method you show).

Comment: Thanks you, I will give that a try `Sub GoFast(Optional Reset As Boolean=False)`

Comment: Tim do I call the sub at the begining of a macro like this `GoFast False` and at the end like this `GoFast True` to turn back on `ScreenUpdating` and `EnableEvents`.  Thanks

Comment: You can just use `GoFast` for the first call - the parameter is optional and if you don't provided it, it will automatically be given the value `False`.